# Listening to rabbitmq queue on a remote host

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I want to listen to listen on a queue which isnt on the same host. Is this possible. In the rabbitmq docs I just found information how to send to remote queue but not how to receive. May be this isnt intended?
I tried this code. But that didnt work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import pika
import sys
from datetime import datetime

QUEUE="LMS"
DATE=datetime.now()
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('USERXX', 'PWXX')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('172.16.1.48', '5672', '/', credentials)
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE)


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print("Neue Nachricht:  %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(
    queue=QUEUE, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print(' Warte auf nachricht in Queue', QUEUE, ' Abbrechen mit  CTRL+C')

channel.start_consuming()
```

Can anybody tell me if its possible with pika, and if yes how?

thanks in advance

Comment: yes it is possible, what does it mean "Didn't work", what kind of the problem do you ahve?

Comment: what means didn't work? Is this destroyed your computer or is this display error message or is this freeze? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with `pika` because I uses [paho-mqtt](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/) with [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) but mosquitto has also console/terminal tools to work with queue so I could test it. Maybe `rabbitmq` has some console tools to work with queue. And to receive message you have to send new messages - it may not get old messages.

Comment: thank you for your answers and informations.

This is the Error: 

 ./rabbit_receive.py
  File "./rabbit_receive.py", line 10
    channel = connection.channel()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

But I dont see any syntax mistake

Comment: always put FULL error message in QUESTION, not in comment. You should do it at start - we can't read in your mind and don't expect that we will run code to see error message.

Comment: you forgot `)` in line 9 - you have two `(` but only one `)` in this line

Comment: thanke you now i have the follwing error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rabbit_receive.py", line 22, in <module>
    queue=QUEUE, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
TypeError: basic_consume() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_message_callback'

Comment: check documentation - it seems `basic_consume` can't get argument `on_message_callback`. Maybe it has different name.

Comment: I see you use very old `python 2.6` - maybe it is old version of `pika` which doesn't have this argument.

Comment: thanks for your answers. this could be the reason. I check this out

Answer (score 0):

the reason was the old python version. thanks for your helpt